# Baixar arquivo pelo dispositivo mobile

Tags: html5, mobile

Tenho um link, e ao clicar nesse link ele realiza o download de uma imagem. Até aí tudo bem, mais quando eu acesso de algum dispositivo mobile eu não consigo baixar este arquivo, alguém tem alguma ideia ou solução para resolver isso?

HTML:

```
<a href="http://mlb-s2-p.mlstatic.com/ipad-mini-apple-16gb-wi-fi-100-original-pronta-entrega-16713-MLB20125338106_072014-F.jpg" download>
    Clique para baixar a imagem
</a>
```

JSFIDDLE:

http://jsfiddle.net/dv381tga/

Comment: Cara, quais navegadores você testou? Alguns navegadores oferecem mais suporte à HTML5 que outros!

Comment: Exemplo: Safari (pelo iPad), Internet Explorer (Windows Phone), Chrome (iPad e Android).

Comment: Justamente Safari e Internet Explorer não suportam o atributo download. Versões mais novas do Chrome e do Opera suportam.

Comment: Certo. Então eu testei pelo Chrome (iPad) e não funcionou, pelo que eu vejo a tag a download é suportada pelo Chrome

Comment: olha aqui: http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/training/basics/data-storage/files.html

Comment: meu celular Android baixa arquivo numa boa...?

Comment: Não sei como é no Android e no Windows Phone, mas no iOS acho que você simplesmente não pode fazer downloads.

Comment: @Danilo não tenho algo com iOS para testar, mas olhando em http://mobilehtml5.org/ parece que a aderência do Chrome ao HTML 5 em iOS é a mesma do Safari. Neste caso, em iOS, talvez a única opção seja o Opera. Dependendo de quem é seu público-alvo, você pode tentar usar um href codificado em base-64 (mais ou menos como feito em: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26721964/1156498 ) utilizando um tipo MIME adequado para a sua imagem (eu tentaria application/octet-stream).

Answer (score 2):

Você pode tentar fazer isso, mas ele não dá suporte a todos os navegadores:

```
<a href="/caminho/imagem" download="arquivo-para-baixar.jpg" title="Nome da imagem">
    <img src="/caminho/imagem/arquivo-para-ver.jpg" alt="Nome da imagem">
</a>
```

### Exemplo de uso

Veja qual é suportado aqui: http://caniuse.com/#feat=download.

Mas você pode tentar usar o **modernizr** para isso: http://modernizr.com/download/#-a_download

Outra forma e criando um .htaccess com seguinte regra:

```
<Files (arquivo1|arquivo2).jpg>
   ForceType application/octet-stream
   Header set Content-Disposition attachment
</Files>
```

### Modelo com Fiddle

Comment: Não vi nenhuma diferença pelo exemplo que eu disponibilizei na pergunta

Comment: @Danilo, se você notar, no meu exemplo, o atributo está recebendo o parâmetro da imagem, talvez seja esse o motivo de não estar conseguindo baixar seu arquivo. Se existir outra forma de fazer isso, que eu desconheça, sugiro que compartilhe na comunidade do SOpt. Além disso, eu sugeri uma API que permite ser implementada para o seu download.

Comment: Aqui tem mais sobre a API: https://modernizr.com/docs/#using-modernizr-with-javascript

Comment: Podes fazer um JSFIDDLE dessa sua resposta?

Comment: Poderia mas não vejo necessidade, já que se trata apenas de uma simples tag de link. E ainda que eu faça, o teste deverá ser feito a partir de um celular.

Comment: Por isso, gostaria de fazer esse teste no celular, como é um simples fsfiddle

Comment: Esse link já não resolve? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_a_download2

Comment: Não. Testei ele em todos as plataformas mobiles e não faz o download da imagem. :/

Comment: Vc tem que usar /path/, não funciona usando domínio. Coloquei um exemplo com fiddle.

Comment: Também não funcionou

Comment: Eu dei +1 pela ideia server-side em htaccess

Answer (score 1):

Danilo, não há uma forma de se fazer isso consistentemente do lado cliente. Você teria que usar uma solução servidor para garantir que o download aconteça.

Veja um exemplo em PHP bem difundido:

1. Sua imagem no front-end (lado cliente):

```html
<a href="download.php?imagem=caminho/absoluto/da/imagem.jpg">
    <img src="caminho/absoluto/da/imagem.jpg"/>
</a>
```

2. No lado servidor:

```html
<?php

$imagem = $_GET['imagem']; #pega o caminho absoluto da imagem a partir do link

baixar_imagem($imagem); #executa a funcao abaixo que tem o caminho absoluto da imagem como parametro

function baixar_imagem( $camingo_absoluto_da_imagem ){

  // Verifica se os cabeçalhos da pagina de download foram enviados
  if( headers_sent() ){
      die('Cabeçalhos de página já enviados!');
  }
    

  // Essa parte é requerida em alguns navegadores
  if(ini_get('zlib.output_compression')){
      ini_set('zlib.output_compression', 'Off');
  }
    

  // Primeiro, verificamos se a imagem existe
  if( file_exists($camingo_absoluto_da_imagem) ){

    // Depois, verificamos a extensao da imagem para podermos saber seu tipo MIME
    $tamanho_da_imagem = filesize($camingo_absoluto_da_imagem);
    $trecho_caminho_imagem = pathinfo($camingo_absoluto_da_imagem); //veja mais sobre a função pathinfo() do PHP
    $extensao = strtolower($trecho_caminho_imagem["extension"]);

    // Agora, verificamos o tipo da imagem a partir da extensao
    switch ($extensao) {
      case "gif": $tipo_imagem="image/gif"; break;
      case "png": $tipo_imagem="image/png"; break;
      case "jpeg": $tipo_imagem="image/jpg"; break;
      case "jpg": $tipo_imagem="image/jpg"; break;
      default: die('Imagem não foi encontrada');
    }

    header("Pragma: public"); // requerido
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Cache-Control: private",false); // requerido em certos navegadores
    header("Content-Type: $tipo_imagem");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".basename($camingo_absoluto_da_imagem)."\";" );
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
    header("Content-Length: ".$tamanho_da_imagem);
    ob_clean();
    flush();
    readfile( $camingo_absoluto_da_imagem );

  } else{
      die('Imagem não foi encontrada');
  }
    

}
```

**Informações:**

1. Funções PHP utilizadas:

   - [headers_sent()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.headers-sent.php)
   - [ini_get()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ini-get.php)
   - [ini_set()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ini-set.php)
   - [file_exists()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-exists.php)
   - [filesize()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filesize.php)
   - [pathinfo()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.pathinfo.php)
   - [strtolower()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.strtolower.php)
   - [header()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.header.php)
   - [ob_clean()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.ob-clean.php)
   - [flush()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.flush.php)
   - [readfile()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.readfile.php)
   - [die()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.die.php)

Comment: No caso a meu arquivo já está sendo gerado e vindo pelo servidor. Em pc tudo funciona, o problema é quando eu acesso via mobile como a questão diz. No mobile ele nao faz download utilizando o atributo download na tag <a>