# Ha como inverter os eventos do click do mouse?

Tags: javascript, click, mouse

Me bateu uma dúvida recente, onde o `click` do **botão esquerdo** do mouse poderia em um caso específico passar a ser o **direito**, e vice versa.

## Código

```
var menulist = document.oncontextmenu;

var menu = function(ev) {
    if (ev.button == 0 || ev.button == 1) {
        menulist = new Function("return true;");
            alert('Esquerdo');
    } else {
        if (ev.button == 2 || ev.button == 3) {
            alert('Direito');
        }
    }
}
document.onclick = menu;
document.oncontextmenu = new Function("return false;");
```

O que realmente pretendo com isso, é **definir o botão direito** como o primeiro, para aplicar sobre um link que contém um arquivo para *download*. Ao invés de disparar um aviso para o internauta utilizar o **botão direito** para *Save Link As...*.

[image: screenshot]

Claro que, seria ideal apenas jogar `oncontextmenu` do **botão direito** para o **botão esquerdo** quando sobre o link para o qual foi especificado. Então o **botão direito**, perde sua ação neste dado momento.

> **Resumo** - *"Quero saber como aplicar comportamentos internos do JavaScript a chamar o `oncontextmenu` no `onclick`."*

Comment: Se deseja que o usuário baixe porque não utiliza o atributo "download" no link, não seria mais fácil? Exemplo: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/100332/15089

Comment: @Inkeliz Ja fiz teste com método `download`, mas mesmo assim o video abriu dentro do navegador, ou seja, ele foi baixado pra dentro do player nativo do navegador e não exibiu a janela para o _download_.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo seu comentário:

> @Inkeliz Ja fiz teste com método download, mas mesmo assim o video abriu dentro do navegador, ou seja, ele foi baixado pra dentro do player nativo do navegador e não exibiu a janela para o download.

Me parece que o que você deseja é garantir que o conteúdo será descarregado para a máquina do usuário, e não exibido no navegador.

Você não conseguirá controlar isso por Javascript. Seria uma falha de segurança poder controlar os dispositivos do usuário dessa forma.

O que você pode fazer é informar ao navegador o [tipo MIME](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME) do conteúdo que é acessado pelo endereço do link. Isso é feito do lado do servidor. Experimente fazer com que o tipo MIME do arquivo em seu link seja algo como "application/octet-stream". Isso deve fazer com que todos os navegadores modernos entendam que o conteúdo deve ser descarregado como arquivo/ficheiro.